# Hide login/register after authentication

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, acl, fosuserbundle

I'm looking for a working solution, to hide pages from authenticated users in symfony. Unfortunately, the default user roles are *staggered*. The following configuration does not work:

```
# app/config/security.yml
access_control:

    # This rules works not:
    - { path: ^/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

    # This rule works:
    - { path: ^/logout$, role: roles: [ROLE_USER] }
```

For my opinion, this ruleset should end up in a HTTP 404 Unauthorized after visiting `/login` or `/register` as a authenticated user (`UsernamePasswordToken`) - but it does not!

After some reasearch, I found more information. According to [Symfony 2 documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/remember_me.html), users are automatically given one of the following roles depending on how they are authenticated:

1. `IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED`
2. `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY`
3. `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY`

> If you have the `IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED` role, then you also have
>   the `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` role. If you have the
>   `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` role, then you also have the other two roles.
>   In other words, these roles represent three levels of increasing
>   "strength" of authentication.

[image]

In other words: There seems to be *no possible way*, to hide pages from a authenticated user...

---

#### 1. Possible solution - Use a static role *(does not work...)*

Using the access control role `IS_ANONYMOUS` could be great option, but it does not work for paths behind a Firewall: Symfony will append a `AnonymousToken` to your session each time you visit any page behind `^/`:

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
...
```

---

#### 2. Possible solution - Edit all controllers *(takes way too long...)*

I ended up rewriting all controllers (.....) and implemented custom, *hard-coded* access rules into the controllers.

---

I hope, somebody has a smiliar problem and a simple stupid solution.

Comment: Know your framework before telling *it sucks* :) [expression-language](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-the-expressionlanguage-component#access-control-rules) to the rescue ... either use symfony 2.4 or add JMSSecurityExtraBundle to your application. Read the expression language introduction and/or [this blogpost](http://henrik.bjrnskov.dk/symfony2-anonymous-users-access) to get an idea ...

Comment: @nifr You are a real symfony foreman - thank you  !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily solve this with the use of the [expression-language](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language/index.html) component ( symfony ~2.4):

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/whatever, allow_if: "!is_fully_authenticated()" }
```

For symfony <2.4 you can use [JMSSecurityExtraBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSecurityExtraBundle) which provides expression-based security rules aswell.

> request, token and user are the variables you have access to and
>   is_anonymous(), is_authenticated(), is_fully_authenticated(),
>   is_rememberme(), and has_role() are the functions defined in this
>   context.

Read more about the expression-language:

- [introduction](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-the-expressionlanguage-component#access-control-rules)
- [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language/index.html)
- [syntax](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language/syntax.html)